# Canonical projection and projectable vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a Lie group, with $\mathfrak{g}$ its Lie algebra. Given $X \in \mathfrak{g}$, one can define a vector field
$$ (X^R) := d_e R_g(X) $$
with $e$ the identity of $G$. On the other hand, if $H$ is a closed subgroup of $G$, one has a quotient space $G/H$ and a unique differential structure such that the projection map
$$\pi: G \to G/H$$
is a submersion.

**Question:**  The vector field $X^R$ is $\pi$-projectable, i.e., for every $g,k \in \pi^{-1}(p)$ (for some $p$), it holds that $\pi_*(X^R)_g = \pi_*(X^R)_k$.

What have I done: Given the left action $\rho: G \times G/H \to G/H$, defined as
$$ \rho(g, k \cdot H) = (g \cdot k) \cdot H$$
I have proved that $\pi \circ L_g = \rho_g \circ \pi$, with $\rho_g = (g, \_)$. This equality supposedly helps in the main question, but I did not figure out how. If someone can point out how to proceed (with or without this hint), I would be grateful.

Comment: Observe that by the your identity for $g,h\in \pi^{-1}(p)$ we have $$\pi (hg)=(\pi\circ L_h)(g)=\rho_h(\pi(g))=\rho_h(\pi (k))=\pi(hk) $$ for all $h\in G$ and combine this with $$X^R_g=(dR_g)_eX=\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}(\exp tX) g.$$

Comment: In this case, I have $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t = 0}(\operatorname{exp}tX)g = Xg$, right?

Comment: $X\in \mathfrak{g}$ and $g\in G$, so $Xg$ isn't a meaningful expression.  $\exp tX$ is a curve in $G$ which passes through $e$ at $t=0$ with velocity $X\in \mathfrak{g}$, so when we compose it with $R_g$ and take the derivative at $t=0$ we get $(dR_g)_eX$ which is equal to $X^R_g$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X^R\in \mathfrak{X}(G)$ is the right invariant vector field generated by $X\in \mathfrak{g}$ then the integral curve of $X^R$ which passes through $g\in G$ is $$c_g(t)=\exp tX g = R_g(\exp tX).$$ Moreover, by your identity if $g,k\in \pi^{-1}(p)$ then $$\pi(hg)=(\pi\circ L_h)(g)=\rho_h(\pi(g))=\rho_h(\pi(k))=\pi(hk)$$ for any $h\in G$.  In particular, if we take $h=\exp tX$ then we find that for $g,k\in \pi^{-1}(p)$ $$\pi(c_g(t))=\pi((\exp tX) g)=\pi((\exp tX) k)=\pi(c_k(t))$$ for all $t$.  Then we simply take derivatives of both sides $$\pi_*X^R_g=\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}\pi(c_g(t))=\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}\pi(c_k(t))=\pi_*X^R_k.$$

Comment: I understand now. Thank you!